# django pagination error: AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Get'

Tags: django

I am having a hard time with django pagination. Can someone help me out with this?

This view is returning an error:

```
def view_homePage(request, user):
if user == 'all':
    posts = Post.objects.order_by("-timestamp").all()
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 2)
        
    ERROR ---> page_number = request.Get.get('page') or 1
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    return JsonResponse([post.serialize() for post in page_obj], safe=False)
```

The error I am getting is: `AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Get'`

If I remove the line and just set `page_number = 1` for testing I have a new set of issues. How do I actually pass the page number to the view from the html page?
I tried adding this for testing, but it does not work:

```
<nav aria-label="...">
     <ul class="pagination">
         <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" 
               href="?page=3">3</a>
         </li>
     </ul>
 </nav>
```

On the above code I hard coded page 3 just for testing, but it does not get into the view. How do I go about this? The django documentation is lacking in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The querystring is stored in a `QueryDict` in the [**`.GET`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET) of the `request`, so:

```
page_number = request.GET.get('page') or 1
```

Note that Django's identifiers are case *sensitive*, so `.GET` and `.Get` are different.

Comment: My second question, is how do I actually pass the page number to the view from html?

Comment: @chris26jp: this is in the querystring, so the part after the `?`, so that is for example `/path/to/the/view?page=2` to pass `2` to the `'page'` key in `request.GET`.

Comment: @chris26jp: I don't really see what the problem is, you can `fetch('/homepage/?page=' + n)` with `n` the page number.

Comment: Perhaps my design has gotten me in trouble then. The entire page is built dynamically with javaScript. JS calls the view with a fetch, the view returns the data back to JS to dynamically build the page. Should I be looking at a JS alternative to pagination?

Comment: @chris26jp: if the user is dynamic as well, you can combine the two, so `fetch('/homepage/' + n + '?page=' + p)` with `n` the `user` and `p` the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222460/discussion-between-chris26jp-and-willem-van-onsem).